# How can I disable the result set returned from an EXECUTE STATEMENT on MYSQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL 5.6 version InnoDB and I've created an stored procedure to run the ANALYZE TABLE to all objects from my schema.
So I do a LOOP using a CURSOR and every single FETCH, I run a PREPARE STATEMENT EXECUTE, like this:

```
...
OPEN CURSOR_TABLE_LIST;
LOOP_TABLE_LIST: LOOP
  
  FETCH CURSOR_TABLE_LIST INTO vTableName;
    
    SET @full_stmt = CONCAT('ANALYZE TABLE mySchema.', vTableName);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @full_stmt;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    IF vExitLoop THEN
      CLOSE CURSOR_TABLE_LIST;
      LEAVE LOOP_TABLE_LIST;
    END IF;
     
END LOOP LOOP_TABLE_LIST;
...
```

The problem is: every single prepare statement execution the ANALYZE process return a resultset with 4 columns and I'm using MySQL Workbench. So if in my schema exists too many tables my Workbench freeze and stop running.

How can I silent, disable, omit or suppress an EXECUTE STATEMENT return?
I know that to simple SELECT statements I can use this:

```
SET @foo = (SELECT COL FROM TAB);
```

But can I do something like that to a PREPARE STATEMENT structure?
Another possible solution that I've tried it's programming that prepare statement block in another "generic procedure", but I didn't find out a way to silent the return from a CALL PROCEDURE, either...

```
CALL SP_EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE('ANALYZE TABLE mySchema.myTable');
```

I'm new using the MySQL... maybe can I put that return in a table?
It's quite different from PLSQL or T-SQL... Any ideas?
Thank's a lot!
[]'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analyze table optionally allows you to analyze multiple tables

```
ANALYZE [NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG | LOCAL]
    TABLE tbl_name [, tbl_name]
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html

and maybe this is more appropriate than the one at a time approach you have just now.

Comment: Thank's P.Salmon! You're right, because when I'm using multiple tables executed in just one command the resultset is returned in just one tab. I didn't disable the output, but my workbench is working fine. Thank for your suggestion, my friend!!